# Remove everything before a certain occurrence identified by position in string

Tags: r, regex, string, stringi

I have a string looking like `a`.

I would like to delete everything before the 2nd to last occurrence of the patter `=== test`, `===` included.

```
a <- "=== test : {abc}
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {aUs*} 
      === dce
      === test : {12abc}
      === abc
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {dfg}"

result <- "test : {abc}
           === test : {dfg}"
```

I tried:

```
gsub(".*=== test", "", a)
```

How to set the index 2nd to last?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have newlines here? Please [use `dput` to provide a valid MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `strsplit` to split by line breaks and pick the last two elements. `paste` them together and use `sub` to remove the `===` in the beginning:

```
sub("^=== ", "", paste(tail(strsplit(a, split = "\\n")[[1]], 2), collapse = "\n"))
# [1] "test : {abc}\n=== test : {dfg}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work. I split the data into a vector separated by newline `\\n` (the additional backslash is to "escape" the special character) and then used `grep` to find all occurances of the pattern `^=== test` the leading `^` means the string should begin with this.

**DATA**

```
a <- "=== test : {abc}
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {aUs*} 
      === dce
      === test : {12abc}
      === abc
      === test : {abc}
      === test : {dfg}"
```

**CODE**

```
# convert to a vector for ease
b <- unlist(strsplit(a, '\\n'))

# get indices for each occurrence of the pattern  
indices <- grep('^=== test', b)

# we only need the last two occurrences 
n <- length(indices)

res <- b[indices[(n-1):n]]

# res is a vector with two entries, to get it back to a single entry 
# same as the original data, we use paste(.., collapse = '\\n')
result <- paste(res, collapse = '\\n')
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> result
[1] "=== test : {abc}\\n=== test : {dfg}"
```

Comment: I have a dataframe for which a columns contains a string like that in each row, so I would need to iterate it for each row ... I will try to see how it performs @Gautam

Comment: You can do all of this in a single call as well. I expanded it here to show what the code does. You can wrap the single call in function and use `lapply` to run it on all rows of the `data.frame` object.

Comment: @thequietus Maybe you should then provide the dataframe in your question, and your expected output.